# Why is the "WHERE" query not working with SQLITE in php

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, xampp

**Edit:The problem's been solved.I used PDO's prepared statement to use where by using ? in place of the variable and then later binding it with the variable string.**

I have used the below mentioned sql query to join two tables and display there data.Here it is

```
SELECT docinfo.fnamedoc,docinfo.lnamedoc,docinfo.department, 
prescriptions.prescription FROM docinfo INNER JOIN prescriptions
ON docinfo.unamedoc=prescriptions.unamed
```

When i use an additional WHERE alongside this statement than i am it works with an SQL DB software "DB browser for SQLite" when i run the sql code on it but it isnt working with php.Nothing gets displayed when i use where but the code in php works when i dont use where.

The code with WHERE is as follows:

```
SELECT docinfo.fnamedoc,docinfo.lnamedoc,docinfo.department, 
prescriptions.prescription FROM docinfo INNER JOIN prescriptions
ON docinfo.unamedoc=prescriptions.unamed WHERE prescriptions.unamep=$uname`
```

The picture of query running successfully in "DB browser for sqlite" and displaying one row is as follows
[SQL Query in DB Browser for SQLITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3x1A.png)

Comment: Don't know sqlite but probably because `$uname` is a string and needs to be quoted. Should parameterize if the PHP driver offers that (if not you should probably find a different driver).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info How do I make my database queries secure from SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

The problem's been solved.I used PDO's prepared statement to use where by using ? in place of the variable and then later binding it with the variable string using $db->Bindparam(1,$uname).I still dont know what was causing it but now its solved.